# Problem with defining choosing function for a profunctor lens

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I'm fiddling with profunctor optics and I've some up against something I can't quite figure out.

The profunctor encoding of Lens and its inversion is as follows:

```
type Optic p s t a b = p a b -> p s t

type Lens s t a b = forall p. Strong p => Optic p s t a b

type LensyReview t b = forall p. Costrong p => Optic p t t b b
```

you can freely convert between them back and forth using

```
newtype Re p s t a b = Re { unRe :: p b a -> p t s }

instance Profunctor p => Profunctor (Re p s t) where
  dimap f g (Re p) = Re (p . dimap g f)

instance Strong p => Costrong (Re p s t) where
  unfirst  (Re p) = Re (p . first')
  unsecond (Re p) = Re (p . second')

instance Costrong p => Strong (Re p s t) where
  first'  (Re p) = Re (p . unfirst)
  second' (Re p) = Re (p . unsecond)

re :: Optic (Re p a b) s t a b -> Optic p b a t s
re optic = unRe (optic (Re id)))
```

Now, I tried to implement choosing function (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.17/docs/Control-Lens-Lens.html#v:choosing) for a profunctor lens.

It turns out that this requires additional type class:

```
class Profunctor p => SumProfunctor p where
  (+++!) :: p a b -> p a' b' -> p (Either a a') (Either b b')
```

then if we include SumProfunctor in Lens, we can write

```
choosing :: Lens s t a b -> Lens s' t' a b -> Lens (Either s s') (Either t t') a b
choosing optic optic' = \pab -> optic pab +++! optic' pab
```

but then there needs to be another "dual" type class that follows the pattern for Re such that

```
instance Unknown p => ProfunctorSum (Re p s t)
instance ProfunctorSum p => Unknown (Re p s t)
```

so that Lens is reversible.

The closest I came up with was:

```
class Profunctor p => Unknown p where
  unsum :: p (Either a a') (Either b b') -> (p a b -> r) -> (p a' b' -> r) -> r
```

as there is a sensible instance for Tagged of it and then you can write

```
instance Unknown p => SumProfunctor (Re p s t) where
  Re f +++! Re g = Re (\s -> unsum s f g)
```

but defining it in the other direction, i.e.

```
instance SumProfunctor p => Unknown (Re p s t) where
  unsum = ???
```

doesn't seem possible.

Am on on the right track or some other method is needed?

Answer (score 1):

`SumProfunctor` is equivalent to [Choice](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/profunctors-5.3/docs/Data-Profunctor-Choice.html#t:Choice), with `p +++ q = left p . right q`

[Cochoice](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/profunctors-5.3/docs/Data-Profunctor-Choice.html#t:Cochoice) is the dual class:

```
instance Cochoice p => Choice (Re p s t) where
    left' (Re f) = Re (f . unleft)
    right' (Re f) = Re (f . unright)

instance Choice p => Cochoice (Re p s t) where
    unleft (Re f) = Re (f . left')
    unright (Re f) = Re (f . right')
```

Comment: That doesn't seem right. Even if you do  newtype OpticN p a b s t = OpticN { runOpticN :: p a b -> p s t } and write Profunctor and Choice instances, then f +++ g = OpticN $ runOpticN (left' f) . runOpticN (right' g) has a different type signature.

Comment: I don't follow you.  I think you can write `instance Choice p => Choice (OpticN p s t)`; I haven't checked it.  Then `(+++) :: (Category p, Choice p) => p -> p -> p` works with the definition I gave above.  I have not worked out whether the `Category` constraint is required for `choosing`.

Comment: Ok, I see, you meant (.) from Control.Category. Look, p +++ q = left' p . right' q has a signature (+++) :: (Choice p, C.Category p) => p s t -> p s' t' -> p (Either s s') (Either t t'), so you need to use my newtype wrapper for types to match (see https://pastebin.com/xxWRmi3w). The other thing is that this is supposed to work for Lenses, which only require Strong, Choice is for Prisms, Folds, Traversals etc. I also thought that Category doesn't play any role here, so that's weird.

Comment: But what is more important, at some point p is supposed to become either Star f (for Traversals), (->) (for Setters), Forget r (for Getters and Folds) or Tagged (for Review). Star f is a category if f is a Monad, but we want f to be only Applicative, (->) is fine, Forget r and Tagged cannot be category (well, I guess you can write (.), but you for sure can't write id).

Comment: So it looks like something weaker is needed, which brings us back to SumProfunctor ;)

Comment: Thank you.  Now I understand your point about `OpticN`.  I don't know the solution, and I won't have more time to tinker with in for a couple of days.

Comment: How about `choosing f g = lens (either (get f) (get g)) (either (flip (set f)) (flip (set g)))` ?